# Losing request attributes when redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, ssl

I am trying to implement login throught SSL on Tomcat.
The login servlet is called IniciarSesion, so I add the following to the web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
            <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>Seguridad en Acceso</web-resource-name>
                 <url-pattern>/IniciarSesion</url-pattern>
            </web-resource-collection>
            <user-data-constraint>
             <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
            </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

The problem now is that when i try to get the input password by doing:

```
String nick=(String)req.getParameter("login");
```

This returns null, the request parameter is losing when redirirecting from http to https.

How can i solve this?

Comment: SSL is not about login. It's about securing the transport layer.

Comment: @Tichodroma you can use the SSL certificates and/or public keys to authenticate users

Comment: @memosdp Yes, but that is not what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Tichodroma i didn't said that for the OP but for you

Comment: i think this is obvious ... the user connected through http and server redirects to https, then the environment is reseted. Just keep the user data in the cache somehow and pass them later in the ssl session

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if your login page (where "login" is defined) is not protected. When it hits your /iniciarSesion servlet via HTTP, tomcat performs an HTTP REDIRECT to the SSL site. True redirects do not preserve the data originally sent to the server, thus you lose the data. My suggestion is to either include your login page in the CONFIDENTIAL scope.

Comment: Yes but the login page is the main page (you have the form on the header), and i dont want to protect all the site

Comment: If you are posting to your servlet via HTTP then you are sending the data with it. Simply adding that directive to your web.xml doesn't protect you from having credentials sent in plain text. To secure it you have no other choice than to have the client POST the data to an https url. You can get the fully qualified path fairly easily using some data in the request and response objects that generated your HTTP page in the first place (or just hard code it).

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of SSL is to secure the transport. If you send login credentials first over http then it makes no sense to redirect to https since you will already have sent the information "in the clear". What you do is post your login-form to the https URL, either by setting the form url explicitly, or by loading your login-page over https. This would involve adding the login-page as a protected resource, just like your login servlet.

Comment: Ok, i was hoping for a solution before having to post the form to the https URL. Now the problem will be dealing with the Servlet context blabla..